# Why do I keep getting $(...).scrollSpy is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I am using bootstrap 4.3.1
popper 1.10.1 and jquery 3.4.1

loaded in the order of
popper
jquery
bootstrap

But using data-spy="scroll" in combination with a target doesnt work, and calling the scrollSpy function myself produces the error: 
`TypeError: $(...).scrollSpy is not a function`

I tried using that data attribute as well as using the manual function. I tried swapping out bootstrap and jquery functions, load errors, pasting the scrollSpy code from twitter bootstrap (which did nothing)

```
<div class="timeline" id="timeline-spy" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#timeline-wrapper">
            <nav class="timeline-nav__wrapper" id="timeline-wrapper">
                <ul class="timeline-nav">
                  ... (list items)
                </ul>
            </nav>
</div>
```

I expect scrollspy to work the way it is described and not throw the `TypeError: $(...).scrollSpy is not a function` error, or just for the data-attribute method to work.

### Edit

All the libraries i load: (It's symfony code but you should be able to tell)

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/selectize.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/custom.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/rpg-icons/css/rpg-awesome.min.css') }}">

<script src="{{ asset('/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/perfect-scrollbar.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/selectize.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/clamp.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/theme/light/sb-admin-2.min.js') }}"></script>
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
<script src="{{ asset('/js/toast.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/build/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Note: They are all in the  of the html file because i'm using turbolinks.

In the picture below you can see that none of the jquery gets overwritten and that the load order is quite correct. The app.js consists of a small amount of js, so it's not reloading jquery there or anything like that.

[image: Loading order]

Comment: are you using any other libraries?

Comment: Show the actual code that loads the libraries and make sure a second jquery library isnt being loaded somewhere else in your code which would overwrite the previously loaded jquery and thus erase any loaded plugins

Comment: sid and patrick evans view my edit

Comment: have you verified your symphony code is generating a valid url to the bootstrap library?

Comment: Yes because everything else relating to bootstrap is working. Also im pretty sure it would throw an exception otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has two dependencies: jQuery 1.9.1 and popper.js 1.12.3. When you install Bootstrap, you need to install these two dependencies.

**In Angular:**

Install popper.js    `npm install popper.js@^1.12.3 --save`

Install jQuery: `npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save`

Install Bootstrap: `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 --save`

If you're using latest version of bootstrap(4.1+) then

For Bootstrap 4.1

```
npm install popper.js@^1.14.3 --save

npm install jquery@3.3.1 --save

npm install bootstrap@4.1.1 --save
```

then just add the package to the scripts in angular.json - the same way you include other js files, but Popper.min.js should be before Bootstrap.min.js

**In HTML:**

include popper.js before Bootstrap js file and the Scrollspy should work just fine. CDN Link: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js.

Comment: It's symfony code but you should be able to tell that I load all 3 of those in (As stated in my original question)

 
   <script src="{{ asset('/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>


(I cant use backticks to make it look any prettier, sadly)

Comment: thats right, just make sure popper.min.js is loaded bu going to that assets folder

Comment: if you still get that error, try removing your cache, history

Comment: which version of jquery & bootstrap is it?

Comment: jquery 3.4.1 (i tried earlier versions too) and bootstrap 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The $(...).scrollSpy() never resolved it self. However, when playing around with some codepens i figured out how to fix the data related one. For me, what fixed it was adding the class 'nav' to the  tag. So it functions properly now.